# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydea'

Tags: pip

I have installed pydea in google colab using pip method.
Now when I am importing pydea as dea, it gives an error.
it says- 'No module named pydea'

Answer (score 0):

The module to import is [`pyDEA`](https://github.com/araith/pyDEA/tree/master/pyDEA), not `pydea`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
first, do: `!pip install pydea`
and then:  `import pyDEA`